# Where can I get 4x5″, 5x7″, or 8x10″ color sheet film (or other hard-to-find exotic film) processed?

Tags: film, developing, business, service-recommendation, alt-process

## Where can I get XYZ exotic film processed?  See below!

### Background:

I've got a 4x5" view camera, and I'd like to shoot some color negatives on it, for printing in a color darkroom that I currently have access to (that, alas, is slated to go away soon).  However, the local lab doesn't do C-41 sheet film, so... I'm wanting to figure out what lab(s) I might be able to send it to.  And I figure this is becoming a more and more rare thing, so, I propose that this question be treated as a clearing-house for information about places that develop color sheet film, or color infrared film of any type (if there still are such places -- I still have a roll or two in my freezer, but I don't think it's possible to get anymore, really), or what have you.

## Format:

My suggestion is for someone to make this a community wiki (please; alas, I don't seem to yet have the rep to do that), with a summary of all the answers in the question, broken down by film type.  And then, the answers can be set up to be one answer per Lab that's relevant to any of the listed film types, with comments under that answer for people to share their experiences with that particular lab.

I'm assuming that many places at this point will be oriented towards dealing with mail-in submissions from around the united states or even globally.  Please specify the city, in case someone happens to be local to it, but also link to a website or provide whatever other contact info might be relevant, so that people can figure out mailing, etc.

## The info!

---

### 4x5" Sheet film

#### 4x5" Black and White:

- [LTI Photographic Services](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6196#6196), New York, New York
- [Praus Productions, Inc.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6195#6195), Rochester, New York
- [Peak Imaging, UK](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19755/5304) Sheffield, UK
- [Reed Art & Imaging](http://www.reedphoto.com/resources/prices/film-developing-processing-prices/), Denver, Colorado
- [North Coast Photographic Services](http://www.northcoastphoto.com/), Carlsbad California --
  processes and scans just about anything 8x10 on down.

#### 4x5" E-6:

- [LTI Photographic Services](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6196#6196), New York, New York
- [Praus Productions, Inc.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6195#6195), Rochester, New York
- [Peak Imaging, UK](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19755/5304) Sheffield, UK

#### 4x5" C-41:

- [LTI Photographic Services](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6196#6196), New York, New York
- [Praus Productions, Inc.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6195#6195), Rochester, New York
- [Peak Imaging, UK](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19755/5304) Sheffield, UK
- [Keeble and Shuchat](http://www.kspphoto.com/), Palo Alto -- sends film to [Swan Labs](http://www.swanphotolabs.com/), in San Clamente
- [Reed Art & Imaging](http://www.reedphoto.com/resources/prices/film-developing-processing-prices/), Denver, Colorado

---

### 120 Roll film

I'm guessing this one is still a lot easier, but it's probably harder than some, so... Break this down by Country/State, and list labs that people might find to be relatively local?  (Do the same with other film types, as needed.)

#### California

- [Keeble and Shuchat](http://www.kspphoto.com/), Palo Alto -- processes B&W and C-41 in-store; will handle E-6, passing off to [Swan Labs](http://www.swanphotolabs.com/), in San Clamente
  Surely lots of others, especially in SoCal.  Please add them.

#### New York State

- [LTI Photographic Services](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6196#6196), New York, New York
- [Praus Productions, Inc.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/where-can-i-get-xyz-exotic-film-processed-4x5-5x7-8x10-color-sheet-film-o/6195#6195), Rochester, New York

#### Washington State

- [Capitol Hill Photo](http://www.capitolhillphotoseattle.com/), Seattle, handles B&W, C-41, and E-6, as well.  Someone who's used them, please fill in further details.
- [R&R Custom Color](http://www.rrcolor.com/), Spokane

Anyone know of a place in Tacoma?  Olympia?  Others?

#### United Kingdom

- [Peak Imaging, UK](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19755/5304) Sheffield, UK

---

### B&W Infra-red

Surely many more

---

### Color Infra-red

Anywhere?

---

## Notes:

- Please add more film types below the above if you're having trouble finding places that will process them.  Be as specific as you think is relevant to the level of difficulty (I'm guessing that 35mm C-41 will still be a while before it needs to be listed here, since many drug stores and such still process it, for example -- E-6 might be sooner, but even there, many drugstores will handle it for you, by passing it off to a lab on your behalf.)
- Please make named links (see examples already existing), and if there's an answer for that lab, link to that answer, instead of the lab's website (linking to the latter from within the answer).
- This is (or should soon be) a community wiki, so please edit as you see fit to make it better!
- Please put a horizontal rule (three dashes) between major categories (types of film) only.

Comment: I totally read that as "erotic film"

Comment: This has been converted to Community Wiki. As such, anyone can edit any of the answers here, as well as the original question. If you have information to fill in @lindes "holes" or placeholders in the OP above, please feel free to edit it and add the information directly.

Comment: Is here the right place to comment that maybe it's interesting to learn to develop sheet film at home, as it's quite expensive (5€ a pop, i believe) and the format lends itself quite well to experimentation/learning and custom development adjustments? just my two cents :)

Comment: Maybe another wiki with development techniques would be nice (will search that)

Comment: I'd love to have info on that! It does strike me as deserving a separate post, but if you find or create one (and I may well do the latter, if you don't beat me to it), please do link to it from here! It's quite relevant to list the option, so just put the link right in the question, above or below all the other links. The details would be too much to put inline, but a link would fit right in!

Answer (score 4):

### [LTI Photographic Services, New York, NY](http://www.ltiny.com/)

**Film Processing:**

- B&W, C-41 and E-6: 35mm to 16x20
- push and pull processing available

**Printing:**

- Optical B&W and C prints
- Digital C prints

**Location:**
30 East 30th Street,
NY, NY 10016

**Phone:**
(212) 685-6871

**Email:**
[info@ltiny.com](http://mailto:info@ltiny.com)

Comment: I process black and white myself but for C-41 4x5 I always go here. A little more expensive than some other labs but they do professional work and offer a student discount. Never had anything lost, scratched, or improperly processed.

Answer (score 3):

### [Praus Productions Inc., Rochester, NY](http://www.4photolab.com/)

Film processing
 - E-6: 35mm to 11x14
 - C-41: 35mm to 8x10
 - B&W: 35mm to 11x14 
 - push and pull processing available

B&W & RA-4 colour printing to large gallery sizes; digital scanning of chrome and negs; digital transfer to chrome; digital printing.

**Location/Mailing address:**
Praus Productions, Inc.
176 Anderson Avenue
Rochester, NY 14607

**Telephone:**
(585) 442-4820

**Fax:**
(585) 442-7124

**email:**
[info@4photolab.com](http://mailto:info@4photolab.com)

Answer (score 2):

## [Panda Photographic Lab, Seattle](http://www.pandalab.com/)

Panda handles:

- Roll film in B&W, C-41, and E-6.  Cross processing, push/pull, etc. all fine.
- B&W Sheet film (4x5" through 8x10")
- "SOON" (see *edit*) TO ADD: E-6 sheet film (4x5", at least) (Should be online c. January 2011? *edit: As of January 2012, it's still not online, but they're still claiming to be working on it.  The claim is that some major plumbing work needs to be done to accommodate it, etc.*)

They also printing, from both digital files (B&W and color) and negatives (black and white only, for darkroom prints).  They can scan to digital, as well.

**Location:**
533 Warren Ave North
Seattle WA  98109

**Phone:**
206-285-7091

**Website:**
http://www.pandalab.com/

Comment: Personally, Panda has been great to me.  From my very first roll there (a heavily bracketed roll of 35mm B&W infra-red, which they printed multiple contact sheets for at different exposures, for no extra charge!), I've had almost nothing but good experiences there.  One or two *minor* mixups (they cut one roll of negatives that I'd asked to have uncut) over several years, which they handled them gracefully (no charge for that roll!).  Very happy with their service.

Answer (score 2):

## [Peak Imaging](http://www.peak-imaging.com)

**International - United Kingdom**

E6, C41 and B&W from 35mm, 120 roll film, 5x4 and 10x8

**Mailing Address**
Peak Imaging
FREEPOST RLSY-YZJX-SLXC
Sheffield
S20 3PP

**Phone**
+44 114 224 3207

Answer (score 1):

[Print Space in NYC](http://www.printspacenyc.com/) does dip and dunk C-41 processing up to 8 X 10 sheet film, at a very competitive price.  There are many 5 star [reviews on yelp.com](http://www.yelp.com/biz/print-space-new-york).

Answer (score 1):

[Citizen's Photo](http://www.citizensphoto.com/), in Portland Oregon, does C-41, and E-6 from 35mm through 8x10", and B&W from 35mm to 4x5".

### Location:

706 SE 6th.
Portland, Oregon 97214

### Phone:

- Phone: (503) 232-8501
- Fax (503) 233-4037
- Toll Free (1-800) 221-3267

### Mailing address (?):

*I'm not sure when you'd use this address versus the other... I'll try to find out and update this answer when I know.*

P.O. Box 14648
Portland, Oregon 97293-0648

### Email:

[lest I worsen their spam load, I refer you instead to [the contact page on their website](http://www.citizensphoto.com/index.html?page=main_contact).]

### Web:

http://www.citizensphoto.com/

Answer (score 1):

**LIGHT WAVES PHOTOGRAPHIC**
   San Francisco, California
   415-431-9651

Professional dip and dunk processing
E6     C41      B&W
35mm through 8x10

www.lightwavesimaging.com

Answer (score 1):

**[BWC Photo Imaging](http://www.bwc.net)** (4930 Maple Ave, Dallas, Texas)

Pretty much everything, including black and white and E6 4x5, 120, and 8x10. Great place.

Answer (score 1):

**Picture Perfect**

2400-A Juan Tabo Blvd NE

Albuquerque, NM

(505) 299-9594

- 120/220 & 35mm *color* and *black & white* film processing
- Film and Transparency Scanning (any size)
- Bulk Scanning
- Digital film restoration

See the website for more services and mail-order instructions:

[www.pixperf.net](http://www.pixperf.net)

No E6 processing, but they will cross-process transparency film in C-41 chemistry.